# SQL Sum to column multiple items from start to current date

Tags: sql-server

I have a need to sum the occurrences of various items in a column from the start up to the current date but not beyond (There is future data) 
My Table looks like this and I want to have the last column as a summed column by each type (Applicaiton In

```
|Task Name|Finish Date| Type|Planned|
|Equate   |1/2/17     | App |1
|TSquare  |2/7/17     | App |2
|Smart    |3/1/17     | Data |1
```

When I don't use a "Until this week" Filter Everyting is great

```
     Select sum (case when 
    Tt.[TaskPercentCompleted] < 100 and Tt.[Task_Significance] like 'Application' 
    Or Tt.[TaskPercentCompleted] < 100 and Tt.[Task_Significance] like 'Data' 
  then 1 else 0 end) as [Planned]
 From [Some table]
```

I get this output - but it counts them all not just until this week. (Then next week -that week etc) 
[image]
However when I add this to the same statement (So I get a date filter)

```
 Select sum(case when 
     [Task_Significance] like 'Application' 
     Or
     [Task_Significance] like 'data' 
     then 1 else 0 end)  over (order by [taskfinishdate] rows unbounded preceding) as Planned
From [Some table]
where
[taskfinishdate] <= DATEADD(DAY, 8-DATEPART(DW, GETDATE()), Convert(date,getdate()))
```

[image]

So again I need to sum by **type** until current date not just as sum of them all.

Comment: Just use `where taskfinishdate < cast(getdate() as date)`

Comment: you need `sum` by type then use `group by type`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you're just trying to count the rows which have a `TaskSignificance` of either `Application` or `Data` - if I understood this correctly then you can accomplish this with a `WHERE` clause, `GROUP BY` and by using `COUNT` in place of `SUM`.

```
SELECT
    COUNT(1) AS Planned
FROM SomeTable
WHERE TaskFinishDate < GETUTCDATE()
  AND TaskSignificance IN('Application', 'Data')
GROUP BY TaskSignificance;
```

The date filtering is handled by the `WHERE` clause, and `COUNT` does not care about the order of the rows, thus the window function i.e. `over (order by ...` is not needed in this case.  You can adjust the date filtering to meet your exact needs.

Comment: Thanks! Great approach! That is why I like this forum - real experts